# Drawing numbers with replacement

Tags: probability

[image]

is the answer 1 - (1/3)^5 because Bob winning is 1/3 ^5

Comment: The probability of Alice losing is $1$ minus the probability of Alice winning. Alice losing is the same thing as Bob winning. But I don't think your $(1/3)^5$ is justified.

Comment: Shouldn't it be $0$, Aice will choose 5 both times.

Comment: Can you fix $\LaTeX$

Answer (score 0):

First consider how may turns it takes Alice to reach 10:

Alice can reach 10 in 2 turns by drawing a 5 followed by a 5, so: $p_{A2}=\frac{1}{3}\frac{1}{3}=\frac{1}{9}$

Alice can reach 10 in 3 turns unless a) she reached 10 in 2 turns $(p=p_{A2}=\frac{1}{9})$ b) she draws 3 3s $(p=\frac{1}{3}\frac{1}{3}\frac{1}{3}=\frac{1}{27})$, so : $p_{A2}=1-\frac{1}{9}-\frac{1}{27}=\frac{23}{27}$

Alice will certainly reach 10 in 4 turns if she hasn't already $p_{A4}=1-p_{A2}-p_{A3}=1-\frac{1}{9}-\frac{23}{27}=\frac{1}{27}$

Bob's chances are exactly the same so:

Alice will win in 2 turns irrespective of Bob's draw $p_{W2}=p_{A2}=\frac{1}{9}$

Alice will win in 3 turns providing Bob doesn't win in 2 $p_{W3}=p_{A3}(1-p_{B2})=\frac{23}{27}(1-\frac{1}{9})=\frac{184}{243}$

Alice will win in 4 turns providing Bob hasn't won in 2 or 3 $p_{W4}=p_{A4}(1-p_{B2}-p_{B3})=\frac{1}{27}(1-\frac{1}{9}-\frac{23}{27})=\frac{1}{243}$

Therefore:

$$p_W=\frac{1}{9}+\frac{184}{243}+\frac{1}{243}=\frac{212}{243}$$